# Chrome show : HTTP hostname and TLS SNI hostname mismatch

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, windows-10

I have problem, when I started my chrome, and try visit https page, i see this error:

Error 1013 Ray ID: 2cb7c5989ac13dd8 • 2016-08-01 08:03:08 UTC
HTTP hostname and TLS SNI hostname mismatch

You've requested an IP address that is part of the CloudFlare network. The request's Host header does not match the request's TLS SNI Host header.

What is it? where place cloudfare and how can I this remove from my browser?

Answer (score 1):

SNI stands for Server Name Indication, essentially it allows you to serve more than one SSL certificate from more than one IP Address. Most modern browsers submit this as part of a web request. [CloudFlare Free Universal SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/) makes use of SNI.

Similarly, the Host header allows a server to know which hostname it should serve. The Host header fundamentally allows virtualhosting, serving more than one website per IP Address.

So these two clearly need to match, the SNI hostname and the hostname in the Host header must be identical. When this fails to occur CloudFlare will present a [Error 1013 HTTP hostname and TLS SNI hostname mismatch](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204872628-Error-1013-HTTP-hostname-and-TLS-SNI-hostname-mismatch).

There may be a proxy in your local network that is stripping out SNI headers or deforming them thus causing them to mismatch. This can happen as a result of a firewall or intermediary web server.

There is a tool here to check if your [SNI header and Host header match](https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/). Simply visit the linked site and check the "SNI information:" field states "cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de".

If you require support for browsers which do not support SNI, CloudFlare's Pro, Business or Enterprise support have legacy support for non-SNI browsers; but it would make sense to contact your network administrator to see why SNI requests are being malformed.

The tags on this question suggest you are using [Firefox on Windows 10 which should support SNI](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69710/which-browsers-support-sni); therefore you should reach out to your network team to see why they are malforming SNI requests.